# Java- Multithreaded call to Cloud and Join all the output

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

In Java Program, I need to use Multithreading to send Inputs to Cloud Integration and I will get Output . Now I need to take all those output values and need to club together and need to do further processing.

So can someone please tell me, how It can be done in the fastest way possible and how I can make sure I have received all the output from the cloud so that I can process further. I am new to this, so please help me.

Comment: There are multiple [ways](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-wait-for-threads) to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will check the given link.

Comment: Maybe this [version](https://medium.com/@senanayake.kalpa/fantastic-completablefuture-allof-and-how-to-handle-errors-27e8a97144a0) of usage of  CompletableFutures is better than you can found in my previous link. With bonus error handling section! :)

Comment: Thanks again @m4gic  !